# Use a member function as callback

Tags: c++, callback, static-members

I would like to use a member function as a callback (using [this function](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#ga7dad39486f2c7591af7fb25134a2501d)):

```
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, (GLFWcursorposfun)(MyClass::mouseButtonChanged));
```

I know it is not possible since I need an instance of `MyClass` to call the method `mouseButtonChanged`.

But what can I do?

Comment: That you're not provided with a mechanism for a user-data pointer in that function somewhat blows. A static map accessible by the callback containing  a mapping of your GLWindow* to your object may be needed. Were the requirement a *callable* (something that support the function `operator()`) I would suggest a `std::bind` solution, but i don't think it will work in your case.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not have c++11 support.

Comment: You don't need C++11 support if you're not using `std::bind`, and regardless of whether you did or didn't ave C++11 support it wouldn't work for you anyway, as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might use `glfwSetWindowUserPointer` to attach a C++ class managing the window. After that you can write a static function forwarding to to a member function of the 'WindowManager'

From http://www.glfw.org/faq.html#how-do-i-use-c-methods-as-callbacks

> 2.16 - How do I use C++ methods as callbacks?
>
> You cannot use regular methods as callbacks, as GLFW is a C library
>   and doesn’t know about objects and this pointers. If you wish to
>   receive callbacks to a C++ object, use static methods or regular
>   functions as callbacks, store the pointer to the object you wish to
>   call as the user pointer for the window and use it to call methods on
>   your object.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass in a function pointer of this type:

```
void (*)(GLFWindow*, double, double)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like they give you a spot for any kind of context argument. So one approach is the global callback approach:

```
struct MyCallback {
    static MyClass* obj;

    static void callback(GLFWindow* window, double a, double b) {
        obj->mouseButtonChanged(window, double a, double b);
    }
};
```

To be used like:

```
MyCallback::obj = &myObj;
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, &MyCallback::callback);
```

That works because `callback` now does not require an instance. Unfortunately, now we have a global `MyClass*` lying around. We're kind of stuck with that though. We can't use a `std::bind()` expression or a lambda here because anything with a capture won't be convertible to a function pointer.

[update] Since you can add a `void*` onto the `window`, you can also do this:

```
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, &myObj);
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, +[](GLFWindow* win, double a, double b){
    static_cast<MyClass*>(glfwGetWindowUserPointer(win))->mouseButtonChanged(win, a, b);
});
```

Where `operator+` on a lambda with no capture (such as the one in this case) converts it to a raw function pointer.

Comment: I have a problem with this line `MyCallback::obj = &myObj;` since I create my instance in main.cpp (which includes MyClass.h); so I don't know how to access it in MyClass.cpp.

Comment: @arthur.sw If you're adding the callback from within `MyClass`, then you'll just want `MyCallback::obj = this;`