# GLFW callback inside class

Tags: c++, class, opengl, glfw

This works:
(main):

```
glfwSetCharCallback(window, Console_Input);
```

(global):

```
void Console_Input(GLFWwindow* window, unsigned int letter_i){
}
```

If I try to put it inside class:
(main):

```
Input_text Text_Input(&Text_Input_bar, &GLOBALS);
glfwSetCharCallback(window, Text_Input.Console_Input);
```

(global):

```
class Input_text{
...
void Console_Input(GLFWwindow* window, unsigned int letter_i){

}
void Update(){
    if(active == 1){
        MBar->Re_set_bar_width(str);
        MBar->update_bar();
    }
}
};
```

It doesnt work. I get error:
cannot convert 'Input_text::Console_Input' from type 'void (Input_text::)(GLFWwindow*, unsigned int)' to type 'GLFWcharfun {aka void (*)(GLFWwindow*, unsigned int)}'
 I dont want to write functionality inside callback function. I need self-managing class. Is there a way to set glfwSetCharCallback to the function inside a class?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298242/callback-functions-in-c?rq=1 for a broad overview of callbacks in C++.

Comment: @MaxLanghof No this is not duplicate. The question is related to GLFW and for GLFW there is a special solution.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, the duplicate was not good. But these should be correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283724/use-a-member-function-as-callback or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676971/pointing-to-a-function-that-is-a-class-member-glfw-setkeycallback (also see https://www.glfw.org/faq.html#216---how-do-i-use-c-methods-as-callbacks).

Answer (score 1):

The callback has to be a function (or static method), but you can associate a user pointer to a `GLFWindow`. See [`glfwSetWindowUserPointer`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga3d2fc6026e690ab31a13f78bc9fd3651).

The pointer can be retrieved at an time form the `GLFWWindow` object by [`glfwGetWindowUserPointer`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga17807ce0f45ac3f8bb50d6dcc59a4e06)

Associate a pointer to `Text_Input`, to the `window`:

```cpp
Input_text Text_Input(&Text_Input_bar, &GLOBALS);

glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, &Text_Input);
glfwSetCharCallback(window, Console_Input);
```

Get the pointer form the `window` and Cast the pointer of type `void*` to `Input_text *` (Sadly you have to do the cast).

```
void Console_Input(GLFWwindow* window, unsigned int letter_i)
{
   Input_text *ptr= (Input_text *)glfwGetWindowUserPointer(window); 
   ptr->Console_Input(window, i); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`void Console_Input(GLFWwindow* window, unsigned int letter_i)`
should be a global function, it cannot be a member function of a class

anwsering your question: no there is no way to put this in a class.